# Ho to update a field in tableA if it contains certain string that is present in another field(in reference table)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to standardise col_value(field) if it contains the string that is present in reference table. The valid_value will be replaced with invalid and the whole string will be updated to updated_col_value in TableA.

```
Table structures:
Basetabe: TableA
col_value,updated_col_value
ReferenceTable
Invalid_value, Valid_value
```

Currently to achieve this, i have written a cursor where i am passing every record and execute update statement. Which is why number of records= number of update statement. It makes my proc really really slow.

I just wanna make it in a single update statement instead of executing updating statement for each time. Could you please help.
Below is my current proc

```
    SET @SQL_STR = 'SELECT col_value FROM TABLEA'

SET @VSQL = 'SET @CURSOR = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR ' + @SQL_STR + ' OPEN @CURSOR;'

EXEC SYS.SP_EXECUTESQL
                @VSQL
                ,N'@CURSOR CURSOR OUTPUT'
                ,@update_column_cusror OUTPUT

fetch next from @update_column_cusror into @Col_value_variable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @updated_col_value_v=''
DECLARE get_valid_value_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Invalid_value FROM REFERENCETABLE
open get_valid_value_cursor
fetch next from get_valid_value_cursor into @invalid_value_variable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin

select @Char_to_replace = Valid_Value  from REFERENCETABLE where Invalid_value=@invalid_value_variable
if @updated_col_value_v=''
set @replaced_value = replace(@Col_value_variable,@invalid_value_variable,@Char_to_replace) 
else
set @replaced_value = replace(@updated_col_value_v,@invalid_value_variable,@Char_to_replace) 

set @updated_col_value_v = @replaced_value


SET @SQL= '
update TABLEA
set updated_col_value='''+@updated_col_value_v+'''
where col_value='''+@Col_value_variable+'''

EXECUTE(@SQL)                                       
fetch next from get_valid_value_cursor into @invalid_value_variable
End
close get_valid_value_cursor
deallocate get_valid_value_cursor
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check following [SQL Server Trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) on main table which validates entries and corrects from reference table

I hope it helps

```
create trigger ValidateEntries on TableA after Insert, Update
as
begin

update TableA
set
    col_value = r.Valid_value,
    updated_col_value = i.col_value
from inserted as i
inner join ReferenceTable r
    on i.col_value = r.Invalid_value
where TableA.col_value = i.col_value

end
go
```

Comment: I am trying to find part of the string if present in the reference table, then corresponding valid value should be replaced.

Comment: inserted is the virtual table that points to new values. the join over columns i.col_value and r.invalid_value filters the rows which has new values on col_value column classified as invalid in the referenceTable

Comment: Let me try this approach and let you know. Hope It makes proc little faster.

Comment: Sure set based operations perform better than cursors, I hope it works as you require